# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-c++, openssl

I need to compile Openssl to use it in Python 2.7 script. I followed the guide here: https://github.com/dsoprea/M2CryptoWindows

I installed ActiveState Perl, NASM, Swig and set the environmental variables.

I run these commands:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nasm
cd C:\grr-build\openssl-1.0.1e
perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\grr-build\openssl
ms\do_win64a.bat
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
```

When I type: `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak` I get error as shown below:

```
C:\grr-build\openssl-1.0.2d>nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Building OpenSSL
        perl .\util\copy-if-different.pl ".\crypto\buildinf.h" "tmp32dll\buildin
f.h"
Copying: ./crypto/buildinf.h to tmp32dll/buildinf.h
        perl .\util\copy-if-different.pl ".\crypto\opensslconf.h" "inc32\openssl
\opensslconf.h"
NOT copying: ./crypto/opensslconf.h to inc32/openssl/opensslconf.h
        rc /fo"tmp32dll\libeay32.res" /d CRYPTO ms\version32.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.3.9600.17336
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        link /nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref /debug /dll /out:out32dll\libea
y32.dll /def:ms/LIBEAY32.def @C:\Users\ADMINI~1.E-A\AppData\Local\Temp\nmDF27.tm
p
tmp32dll\uplink.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts w
ith target machine type 'x64'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x458'
Stop.

C:\grr-build\openssl-1.0.2d>
```

I searched on the web. They said I should run it in VS 64 Command Prompt. I found different types of VS 64 Command Prompts: VS2015 x64 ARM Cross Tools Command; VS2015 x64 ARM Native Tools Command and VS2015 x86 x64 ARM Cross Tools Command. I tried to re-type the command using all of them as I do not know the differences. Nothing worked.

Can you point to me how to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue... it seems like the openssl build on VS2015 does some components in a different processor type or with different run-time options or something; my link fails as well (works fine in VS2013).

Comment: @mark I uninstalled VS2015 and installed VS2013. Still fails. Could you point the guide you used? What exactly environmental variables do I need to add?

Comment: At the VS 2013 64 cmd prompt in a clean openssl folder I do `perl Configure VC-WIN64A` then `ms\do_win64a` then `nmake -f ms\nt.mak`.  Note that this builds into out32 even though they are 64-bit binaries so use another folder or modify the output paths if you want to build debug and/or 32-bit in the same folder.  I have yet to resolve the VS2015 build issue, however...